# Add elements in modal window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a one page website in React. At the moment I have a filter window, implemented with help modal window, that contains four categories and looks like this:

These categories are implemented using a dropdown list, i.e. when opened, checkboxes appear. But this is not visually clear to the user and I would like to fix it.
In the picture below, I have given the desired implementation in green:

Since I have implemented each category for separate files, I gave an example of my code only for the category - date. Please tell me how can I make it happen.

```
    function FilterDate() {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

    const toggleExpand = () => {
        setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
    };

    const collapse = () => {
        setIsExpanded(false)
    }
    const expand = () => {
        setIsExpanded(true)
    }


    const [state, setState] = useState([
        {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: null,
            key: "selection"
        }
    ]);
    return isExpanded ? (
        <div>
            <div onClick={toggleExpand}><h6>Date</h6></div>
            <DateRange
                onChange={item => setState([item.selection])}
                moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                ranges={state}
            />
        </div>
    )
        : (
            <div onClick={toggleExpand}><h6>Date</h6></div>
        );
}

export default FilterDate;
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with adding the arrow at the end of the row?

Comment: @Enve Yes, with an arrow. And also with lines above and below (I marked them in green)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change your return so that the `div` doesn't repeat.

```
return <>
  <div onClick={toggleExpand}><h6>Date</h6></div>

  {
    isExpanded && <div>
      <DateRange
        onChange={item => setState([item.selection])}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        ranges={state}/>
    </div>
  }
</>
```

Add a class to the div, and with CSS add border top and border bottom:

```
<div className="item-toggle" onClick={toggleExpand}><h6>Date</h6></div>

.item-toggle {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

As for the arrow, you can find one in [Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons&icon.query=arrow) and add it inside the div, for example:

```html
<div className="item-toggle" onClick={toggleExpand}>
  <h6>Date</h6>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 12l-1.41-1.41L13 16.17V4h-2v12.17l-5.58-5.59L4 12l8 8 8-8z"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you!!! Only "Date" and arrow on different lines. Perhaps you can tell me how to make the arrow be on the same line with the inscription "Date"?

Comment: You can use CSS for that as well. Here is a flexbox solution, add it to the same CSS where you added the border: `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;`